# Is it possible to remove order from Hibernate Criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, sql-order-by, criteria

If I have an @OrderBy("someProperty") annotation on an object and then use a Criteria to add an ORDER BY clause like so:

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
```

The resulting SQL will do the ordering like this:

```
ORDER BY someProperty, id asc
```

Is it possible to change the order of the two or to remove the someProperty order? I can't remove the @OrderBy annotation and I'm using Hibernate for Java.

Comment: I have this same question... we are using Hibernate 3.2.6...  would love the ability to 'override' the @OrderBy annotation when using projections.  Does anyone know about this?  Is there a way to change it on the fly? Change either the order of the orders, or remove the @OrderBy clause all together?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Hibernate 3.6.4, which I've narrowed down to the (bugged) implementation of org.hibernate.loader.JoinWalker#orderBy(final List associations, final String orderBy) on line 820. I believe there is a bug at this line, since the OrderBy on the associations is being merged before the ordering specified on the Criteria. Think about it: if I've specified a desired ordering in a Criteria having Items as the root entity, should Hibernate really be placing the OrderBy specified on the associated Bids first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) has no methods for removal of [Order](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Order.html) neither [Criterion](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion.html)
[Order](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Order.html) class is very limited, you can only use property names and it generates standard and portable SQL.
OrderBy annotation is a SQL order, as javadoc states: [OrderBy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/OrderBy.html)
That means you can use there any sql (even a exclusive one of your database vendor). Take a look at these article: [Sorting Collections in Hibernate Using SQL in @OrderBy](http://java.dzone.com/news/sorting-collections-hibernate)

*Adding a SQL fragment into your domain class isn't necessarily the most elegant thing in the world, but it might be the most pragmatic thing.*

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible to remove particular ordering via criteria.iterateOrderings() iterator, but I'm not sure how it works with annotations.